# How to join two Set of Objects

Tags: java

I have two sets of objects, where there exists a common 'key' in the objects of each set. I want a resulting set/list that will have join of the properties.
For example,

Set A: `[{id:1,name:john,age:22},{..}]`

Set B: `[{id:1,phone:1234,type:mobile},{..}]`

Set result : `[{id:1,name:john,age:22,phone:1234,type:mobile},{..}]`

Can this be achieved without using using loops or without converting the sets into Hashmap?
thanks.

Comment: "_Can this be achieved without using using loops_". A resounding **no**.

Comment: What's your concern about loops?

Comment: Fun fact, if you are a HashSet (or a child from it), its exactually the same as a HashMap. (Just look at the sourcecodes). So why don't you want to change to a HashMap anyways?

Comment: (Two upvotes? Really?) What is the *contents* of these sets? I mean, which *type* do the objects have? (It looks like they are something like `Map<String,Object>`). When you don't know the type of the objects, and do not know how to "merge" them at all, the question about the loops does not arise at all. (@BoristheSpider ...or the question about recursion ;-))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that your `Set`s are just a visual representation of two Java `Set`s:

```
Set<User>
Set<Phone>
```

Can performing operations on `Set`s be done without loops? Well, probably you can somehow do that with streams, but I would suggest the following:

```
public class UserWithPhone {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Long age;
    String number;
    PhoneType phoneType;

    UserWithPhone(){};
    UserWithPhone(User u, Phone p) {
        if (!u.id.equals(p.id))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.id = u.id;
        this.name = u.name;
        this.age = u.age;
        this.number = p.number;
        this.phoneType = p.type;
    }

    UserWithPhone(User u) {
        this.id = u.id;
        this.name = u.name;
        this.age = u.age;
    }
    setPhoneDetails(Phone p) {
        if (!this.id.equals(p.id))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.number = p.number;
        this.phoneType = p.type;
    }
}
```

Now simply perform the following code:

```
for (User u : users) {
    usersWithPhone.put(u.id, new UserWithPhone(u));
}
for (Phone p : phones) {
    usersWithPhone.get(p.id).setPhoneDetails(p);
}
```

Where `usersWithPhone` is a `Map`. Well... I know that it's not quite what you wanted... I mean there are loops, map... but it's how we do that in Java...

Answer (score 1):

So, it looks like your concern about the loop is more about to avoid brute force approach than actually using loops.

Here's an idea, but it requires that your sets have to be ordered upfront, otherwise there is no way to merge the sets without iterating them a lot of times.

Let's say you have two sets: Users and Phones

```
users =  [{1, "john"}, {2, "ken"}]
phones = [{2, "555-1234"}, {4, "234-23424"}]
```

What you can do is to "iterate" each set while their current id's differ. Now the important point here is to iterate ONLY the set whose id is lower than the other, so if the id in the users is small you walk in the users set, if the id is lower in the phones set you walk the phones set. This way you don't iterate several times each set, but at most you iterate N number of times where N is the length of the Users set.

So in the example you start with id: 1 and 2

```
 users[0].id == 1
 phones[0].id == 2
```

Since they are different you move on the users index

```
 users[1].id == 2
 phones[0].id == 2
```

Now they are the same... in this case you merge the objects and create a new `Contact`

Now you move on both indexes and repeat, unless you're at the end of either of the sets,  in which case you are done.

So, basically something like this pseudo-code

```
// while the id's are different 
while( users[usersIndex].id != phones[phoneIndex].id ) {
    if (user.id < phone.id) { usersIndex++ );
    if (phone.id < user.id) { phoneIndex++ );
}
// At this point either they are the same ... OR one we are at the end of one of the collections
if (user.id == phone.id ) { result.add( new Contact(user, phone) );}
else { we are done }

... repeat.
```

Now, I was trying to do this but it gets tricky, first of all because instances `java.util.Set` don't use indexes, and using the iterators needs a couple of extra verifications and oh yeah, there's your requirement of NOT USING loops. Well it turns out using recursion solves the problem quite well and in a very clean way.

This algorithm using recursion would be something like this:

```
merge( users, phones, results ) {

    // base case, if one of them is empty
    // we're done
    if users.isEmpty() OR phones.isEmpty() 
         return results

    // take the first element on each set and compare them
    user = users.head
    phone = phones.head

    // if they're the same create a new contact and remove them
    if user.id == phone.id 
       results.add( new Contact(user, phone))
       users.remove(user) 
       phones.remove(phone)

    // iterate on the users set
    if user.id < phone.id 
       // we won't find a matching phone
      users.remove(user)

    // iterate on the phone set
    if phone.id < user.id
       // we won't find a matching user
       phones.remove(phone)

    // call again with the modified sets
    return merge(users, phones, results)
}
```

At this point you might think "Yeah, well this is all good but how would I know it works"

Well here's the code, merging two sets without iterating more than N times the sets and creating a new set with the results.

In this example I'm using Lombok [@Data](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data.html) annotation... just because it's awesome, it basically created getters/setters, toString(), equals and hashCode methods for you, so you don't have to write them

```
package merge;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Merge m = new Merge();
        System.out.println("Result= " +
                        m.merge(
                                buildUsers(),
                                buildPhones(),
                                new TreeSet<>()
                        )
        );
    }

    private static Set<User> buildUsers() {
        Set<User> users = new TreeSet<>();
        users.add(new User(1, "j"));
        users.add(new User(3, "k"));
        return users;

    }

    private static Set<Phone> buildPhones() {
        Set<Phone> phones = new TreeSet<>();
        phones.add(new Phone(1, "123"));
        phones.add(new Phone(2, "345"));
        phones.add(new Phone(3, "678"));
        return phones;
        /// KEEP SCROLLING
    }
}

class Merge {
    public Set<Contact> merge(Set<User> users, Set<Phone> phones, Set<Contact> contacts) {

        if (users.isEmpty() || phones.isEmpty()) {
            return contacts;
        }

        User user = users.iterator().next();
        Phone phone = phones.iterator().next();

        if (user.getId() == phone.getId()) {
            addContact(contacts, user, phone);
            users.remove(user);
            phones.remove(phone);
        } else if (user.getId() < phone.getId()) {
            users.remove(user);
        } else {
            phones.remove(phone);
        }

        return merge(users, phones, contacts);
    }

    private boolean addContact(Set<Contact> contacts, User user, Phone phone) {
        return contacts.add(Contact.builder()
                .id(user.getId())
                .name(user.getName())
                .phone(phone.getPhone())
                .build());
    }
}

@Data
class User implements Comparable<User> {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.id, o.id);
    }
}

@Data
class Phone implements Comparable<Phone> {
    final int id;
    final String phone;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Phone o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.id, o.id);
    }
}

@Data
@Builder
class Contact implements Comparable<Contact> {
    int id;
    String name;
    String phone;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Contact o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.id, o.id);
    }
}
```

run

```
javac -cp lib/lombok.jar  src/merge/Main.java -d out/
java -cp lib/lombok.jar:out  merge.Main
Result= [Contact(id=1, name=j, phone=123), Contact(id=3, name=k, phone=678)]
```

Comment: Your generated `equals` and `hashCode` won't be quite consistent with `equals`; not ideal but it shouldn't matter overmuch unless the OP is expecting the `Set` to remove duplicate user ids with different names. I would avoid mutating the `Set` and go for a more functional approach (like your suggested `ConsList` pseudocode) - recurse with `TreeSet.tailSet(item, false)`.

Comment: Consistent with `compareTo` you mean?  You're right, I think there should be a way to make it consistent, probably not making the `String` property final?  About mutating the set, I'm with you, I initially tried to pass the iterator instead but the moment I had some problem with verifying its emptiness I remembered this was a proof of concept and not  a ready for production code and proceeded to remove items from the set to make a working implementation of my algorithm. Gonna take a look to that `TreeSet.tailSet`

Comment: Yes, I meant "_Your `compareTo` won't be quite consistent with your generated `equals` and `hashCode`_". I would add `@EqualsAndHashcode(of="id")` to limit the `equals` to only the `id` property - but it really depends on what exactly the OP expects the behaviour of these objects to be is. You can use `NavigableSet.first()` and `NavigableSet.tailSet`, should produce code almost the same as your conslis.

Comment: thanks a lot. It helped me understand how to approach the problem. And you were right about the "brute force concern for loops"